# create an object in java a class wihtin a class

Tags: java, object

```
public class OutterClass {
    class jiren {
        int a = 20;
        int b = 30;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OutterClass.jiren CA = new jiren(); 
       // (this part shows error)
       // (what do I put before new to //creat the object. ) 
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i create an object for the main. I dont know what to put before new.

Comment: The class `jiren` needs to be `static` in order for you to create instances of it inside the `static` method `main`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should make your inner class static. Also, the Java's convention tells you that the classes should start with an uppercase letter, and the variables with a lowercase:

```
public class OutterClass { 

    public static class Jiren{
        int a = 20;
        int b = 30;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        OutterClass.Jiren ca = new OutterClass.Jiren();
    }

}
```